# Tsql IF...CASE returns syntax error

Tags: t-sql

Much time has been invested in searching for the error. I used 2 other working functions as guides in constructing this, but alas, I am thus far defeated. Can someone tell me why this is returning a syntax error:

```
FUNCTION FN_USER_MATRIX_PriceTweak 
(
@Cost float, @CostAvg float, 
@Tier1MaxVal float, @Tier1Mult float,
@Tier2MaxVal float, @Tier2Mult float, 
@Tier3MaxVal float, @Tier3Mult float,
@Tier4MaxVal float, @Tier4Mult float, 
@Tier5MaxVal float, @Tier5Mult float, 
@Above5Mult float
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Result float

SET @Result = 
(
IF @Cost <= @CostAvg
    CASE
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier1MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier1Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier2MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier2Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier3MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier3Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier4MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier4Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier5MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier5Mult
        ELSE @Cost * @Above5Mult
ELSE    
    CASE
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier1MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier1Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier2MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier2Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier3MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier3Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier4MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier4Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier5MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier5Mult
        ELSE @CostAvg * @Above5Mult
)       

RETURN @Result
END
```

My error messages:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FN_USER_MATRIX_PriceTweak, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FN_USER_MATRIX_PriceTweak, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: You are not using the IF statement properly. You should be using a nested CASE statement instead

Comment: Turns out there were two issues, not fully explained in the intial responses (or help menus):that my CASE statements needed an END statement, a requirement of which I was unaware.

Comment: and secondly, that the right side of SET cannot start with an IF statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
IF @Cost <= @CostAvg
BEGIN
    SET @Result =  CASE
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier1MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier1Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier2MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier2Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier3MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier3Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier4MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier4Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier5MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier5Mult
        ELSE @Cost * @Above5Mult
    END
END
ELSE  
BEGIN
    SET @Result =  CASE
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier1MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier1Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier2MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier2Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier3MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier3Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier4MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier4Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier5MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier5Mult
        ELSE @CostAvg * @Above5Mult
    END
END

RETURN @Result
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a nested `CASE` where you have your `IF...ELSE`:

```
SET @Result = 
(
CASE WHEN @Cost <= @CostAvg THEN (
    CASE
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier1MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier1Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier2MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier2Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier3MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier3Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier4MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier4Mult
        WHEN @Cost <= @Tier5MaxVal THEN @Cost * @Tier5Mult
        ELSE @Cost * @Above5Mult END)
ELSE    
    (CASE
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier1MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier1Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier2MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier2Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier3MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier3Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier4MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier4Mult
        WHEN @CostAvg <= @Tier5MaxVal THEN @CostAvg * @Tier5Mult
        ELSE @CostAvg * @Above5Mult END)
END
)
```